# Apache http connection error

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm a newbie at networking and I'm trying to do the following

1. Setup an Apache HTTP server
2. Setup Username and password
3. Access it from the local network
4. Open the necessary ports
5. Configure the firewall

Now, I was able to do all these things, I have opened port 1500 and checked it online and it does work, I am able to access the server via `http://localhost:1500` on local network.

Everything works as needed except of the most important thing. I cannot access the server from the "outside". I try to access my server from a smartphone on network connection having the router's external ip. Now for debugging's shake is there a way to find any attemped connections to my server/network (to see whether my requests even came through)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apache access logs to see if it's logging any connections.  But it's probably not, because your router isn't letting the connections through.  Use the web interface for your router to forward port 80 or 1500 from the outside to port 1500 on your server, and see if the router has any logging capabilities that can help you figure out where the connection is breaking.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to configure the router. What I've done so far router-wise are these
Set up a Virtual HTTP Server and listening from port 1500 to 1500 using both TCP/UDP and set the Local ip address to 192.168.1.7 which is the pc in which the Apache server is running. Am I correct?

Comment: That sounds right, but routers vary a lot in how you configure them. I haven't heard of a "virtual HTTP server" before, but it sounds as though it wants to forward port 1500 from its public interface to 1500 on 192.168.1.7, which seems to be what you want.  Can you tell if the router is receiving the connections?  Possible your ISP is blocking port 1500?

Comment: My ISP was blocking port 80 so I (randomly) switched to port 1500. I've configured the router to now listen from 80 to 1500. I entered the router's log and saw this

 1/2/2000 23:4:37> Last errorlog repeat 2 Times
1/2/2000 23:4:37> netMakeChannDial: err=-3000 rn_p=804ddd20
1/2/2000 23:4:38> Last errorlog repeat 3 Times
1/2/2000 23:4:38> ppp_ready: ch:805279cc, iface:8046f134
1/2/2000 23:4:39> SNMP TRAP 3: link up
1/2/2000 23:4:39> Accept() fail
1/2/2000 23:4:39> Accept() fail
1/2/2000 23:4:55> LLC 1483 unknow protocol**
1/2/2000 23:7:44> Last errorlog repeat 3 Times
** This error is repeated..